# Xcode, Swift, unrecognised unit test classes/methods

Tags: xcode, unit-testing, swift

I've started a simple SWIFT project: framework + unit test. The idea was to stay in tight TDD cycles, but it quickly fell apart: Xcode stopped recognising unit test methods and I can't find a way to enforce unit tests to be executed.

Each unit test class implements XCTestCase, each method name starts from 'test' prefix.
Code (both tested and tests) compiles without single error or warning.

Even tests which are recognised - are recognised incorrectly as runtime unit tests (rT icon), but at least they run.

Did anyone came across this hurdle?

Sample of not recognised unit test:

```
import XCTest
import Arithmetic
public class VoidNodeTests : XCTest {
    public func testVoidNodeCtor() {
        let tested = VoidNode()
        XCTFail("Not tested yet")
    }
}
```

Comment: The code snippet subclasses `XCTest` instead of `XCTestCase`. Actual code, or just a typo? If not a typo, does changing to `XCTestCase` fix it?

Comment: Spot on! It's embarrassing, but changing inheritance (to XCTestCase) almost fixes it. By 'almost' I mean: all tests are still seen as real time tests, but that's minor inconvenience compared to the previous state. Thank you wightman.

Comment: Cool :-) submitted as answer

Comment: Last Xcode update (to Version 6.1.1 (6A2008a)) sorted the problem with real-time unit tests, so all it's back on track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change superclass from `XCTest` to `XCTestCase`.

Comment: All my test cases extend XCTTestCase by default and I still have this problem.